# Why is the compiler allowing the variable of class "I" to be assigned an object of class "N" which inherits the "I" class

Tags: java, class, variables, types

```
class I {    
    String s="yes its me:I";

    void Mine(){
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}

class N extends I {
    String l="yes its me:N";

    void Mine(){
        System.out.println(l);
    }   
}


class T extends N{
    String m="yes its me:T";
    void Mine(){
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        I i=new I();
        N n=new N();
        T t=new T();
        I r; // r is a variable of class type I

        r=i; // fine here

        r.Mine(); //no doubt here

        r=n; // heres the problem

        r.Mine(); // these are working only 

        r=t; //with overriding methods existing & no other method exists in all classes

        r.Mine();
    }
}
```

Also tell me please: if we declare a variable of class type, what does it do (I mean is it going to recognise by the number of methods and instance variables of the class or only methods or only instance variables).

Comment: Because that's what inheritance means. `N` can be used wherever `I` is required.

Comment: but cant be used when we add a new method to N and compile it then its shows the error...thanks for the answers and comments

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Shows what error? Is this another question?

Comment: Can you explain the last question more clearly?

Comment: I think the confusion was about how/why you would use inheritance to express refinements. Respectively why the compiler would not allow you to access methods of the refinement once casted to a parent type.

Comment: @Ext3h It's up to the OP to clarify. There's no point in everybody else guessing about it.

Comment: @EJP I got what he meant, he assumed that Java uses Duck-Typing.

Comment: also please take a look here.i am begginer...my question may seem stupid but i dont know how java is internally implementing ..can u please take a look on this question too...thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321058/inheritance-in-java-how-to-change-the-variable-value-of-sub-class-by-super-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Vehicle {
    Engine myEngine = new Engine();
    void start() {
        myEngine.start();
    }
    void stop() {
        myEngine.stop();
    }
}
class VehicleWithSteering extends Vehicle {
    Steering mySteering = new Steering();
    void start() {
        mySteering.reset();
        myEngine.start();
    }
    void steerLeft() {
        mySteering.left();
    }
    void steerRight() {
        mySteering.right();
    }
}
```

As you can see, `VehicleWithSteering` does have methods which the basic `Vehicle` did not have. It also overrides the `void start()` method as starting this more complex vehicle involves a different routine.

```
class NoviceDriver {
    Vehicle myVehicle;
    public NoviceDriver(Vehicle vehicle) {
        myVehicle = vehicle;
    }
    void doSomething() {
        myVehicle.start();
        myVehicle.stop();
    }
}
class AdvancedDriver {
    VehicleWithSteering myVehicle;
    public NoviceDriver(VehicleWithSteering vehicle) {
        myVehicle = vehicle;
    }
    void doSomethingElse() {
        myVehicle.start();
        myVehicle.steerLeft();
        myVehicle.stop();
    }
}
```

The `AdvancedDriver` needs additional functionalities which the basic `Vehicle` can not satisfy, so it will always need an instance of `VehicleWithSteering`.

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create one basic vehicle
        Vehicle a = new Vehicle();
        // And one more advanced
        VehicleWithSteering b = new VehicleWithSteering();

        // A novice driver is satisfied with having a basic vehicle
        NoviceDriver x = new NoviceDriver(a);

        // The advanced driver however needs more functionality
        AdvancedDriver y = new AdvancedDriver(b);

        // A novice driver can use the advanced vehicle as well
        // But he will not bother about the advanced functionality
        NoviceDriver z = new NoviceDriver(b);
    }
}
```

The `NoviceDriver` only knows how to access methods of `Vehicle`. But since these methods are also present in `VehicleWithSteering`, he can use that one as well. `NoviceDriver` doesn't even know what steering means so he won't touch any controls he doesn't know about.

You can't fit an `AdvancedDriver` with a `Vehicle` as this one doesn't incorporate the required steering methods.

If there was an even more advanced refinement of the `VehicleWithSteering`, both the `NoviceDriver` and the `AdvancedDriver` could still use it for executing their limited tasks as it still provides the required basic functionalities.

The `NoviceDriver` has access to all public methods and properties the original `Vehicle` had. It does not know about new methods or properties added later on. In this case, it could see the inherited `Engine myEngine` property on the `VehicleWithSteering`, but it can not see the new `Steering mySteering` property.

As for your last question: That depends on the language.

In Java, each class has an internal list of other inherited classes and interfaces it implements. Whenever you are casting a refinement to a more primitive type, Java will check whether the primitive type is in the list or not. This behavior is also used in other strictly typed languages such as C++, C# and many others.

The alternative concept would be Duck-Typing.

> When I see a bird that walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a duck, I call that bird a duck.

When a language uses Duck-Typing, it will look up the requested method in the object by name and signature. This may happen either at compile time or at runtime, in latter case an exception is thrown in most languages supporting Duck-Typing.

Some languages such as PHP and various other scripting languages feature both strict type checks and Duck-Typing. That means you can both optionally enforce a strict type check on the list of inherited classes and implemented interfaces, as well as defaulting to Duck-Typing when that check was omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
class MP3Player // any MP3 player
class IPod extends MP3Player // an iPod MP3 player
class IPodClassic extends IPod // an iPod Classic in particular
```

Then:

```
MP3Player m = new IPod();
m.playMp3();
```

is allowed because an iPod is an MP3 player and can do anything an MP3 player can do.

```
IPod i = new MP3Player(); // Not allowed
i.showAppStore(); // MP3Player might not have app store
```

is not allowed because not all  MP3 player's are iPods.

```
IPodClassic ic = new IPod(); // Not allowed
ic.getHardDisk(); // Not all iPod objects have a hard disk.
```

is not allowed because not all iPod's are iPod classics.