# inheritance in java.how to change the variable value of sub class by super class methods

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

```
class Sup
{
    private int i; //private one,not gonna get inherited.
    void seti(int s) //this is to set i.but which i is going to set becz i is also in child class?
    {
    i=s;
    System.out.println(i+"of sup class"); //to verify which i is changed

    }

}

class Cid extends Sup //this is child class
{
    private int i; //this is 2nd i. i want to change this i but isnt changing on call to the seti method
    void changi(int h) //this one is working in changing the 2nd i.
    {
        i=h;
    }
    void showci()
    {
     System.out.println(i+"of Cid class");   
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Cid ob= new Cid();
        ob.seti(3); //to set i of Cid class but this sets Sup class i
        ob.showci(); //result shows nothing changed from Cid class i
        ob.changi(6); // this works as i wanted
        ob.showci(); // now i can get the i changed of Cid class

    }

}
```

please clarify me that whenever we use inheritance(or extends) does the fields(variables and methods except private ones) do copy to the child(or sub)classes or the fields just can be accessed by the child class?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: i mean can i change the variable existing in Cid class using methods belonging to Sup class.

Comment: No, the code in the `Sup` class can't see the fields in the `Cid` class.  Only code that you write in `Cid` can see a private field in `Cid`.

Comment: but  the variable " i " is same to the both. i thought the "seti" method is inherited and it contains " i " ,so it can change it.

Comment: thats why i asked the below question

Comment: does the fields gets copied or just gets access ?

Comment: In your particular case,  you've got two different `i` fields in each object of class `Cid`.  It's not the same field.

Comment: thank u david wallace but can i assume like the fields are getting copied to sub class when we use extends keyword

Comment: @DavidWallace, there is only one object being constructed here not two; there is no object of type superclass created here. The superclass constructor will be invoked and it's members initialised accordingly, but no superclass object construction.

Comment: @blue, you seem to lack knowledge about the inheritance mechanism in Java. I have explained the rules in my answer below; hopefully it will clear your confusion. If not comment below and I will clarify each rule for you.

Comment: I never said two objects were being created.  Only that if you create an object of class `Cid`, it has two fields called `i`.  Moreover, contrary to @I.K.'s comment, an object of class `Cid` is _indeed_ an object of type `Sup`.

Comment: thanks for u r caring to my question . as far i know, inheritance is just making  an extension of created class(i.e. using written code and extending it, ofcourse  i thought fields are getting copied to the subclasses).is this true..just clarify this one..its all i need

Comment: @blue, if a field is hiding a field in the superclass with the same name and type, the value of the field in the superclass is **not** copied to the field in the subclass.

Comment: @DavidWallace, you have misconstrued my comment. Of course an object of type Cid also has Sup as a type upper bound. What I was meaning to say is that during the construction of the Cid object there is no explicit memory allocated for a separate Sup object. Also re-reading your previous comment, it is clear you did not state that so withdraw my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with an example which could hopefully help you. You could override your super method in a sub class:

super:

```
public class SuperClass {

    private String s = "SuperClass";

    public String getProperty() {
        return s;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(getProperty());
    }
}
```

sub:

```
 public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    private String s = "SubClass";

    @Override
    public String getProperty() {
        return s;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
SuperClass actuallySubClass = new SubClass();
actuallySubClass.print();
```

output:

`SubClass`

So you don't have a direct access to a sub private field as such from the superclass but you could still access it with an overriden getter. In case you need to change the value you could override the setter in the similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

With The Reference to your Question here you just got the access to the The private variable "i" when you extended Sup class you just got seti() method from the sup class that sets the value of var "i" in super class but if you override the seti() method in Cid class Than you will be able to change the value of i in the subclass:

In that case you need to use

```html
Sup s = new Cid();
s.seti(10); // this will change the value of i in subclass class
```